# Redes neurais: como ajustar uma reta nos valores previstos

Tags: redes, matlab, regressão

Não conheço muito esse mundo da inteligência artificial, mas eu tenho um conjunto de dados com a tendência de ser uma função linear, e uma coisa que necessitava era a de achar o coeficiente angular da reta que se ajusta a esses dados.

Usando a regressão linear, consegui achar pelo MATLAB, porém eu quis usar as funções de redes neurais desse software para fazer uma previsão dos valores, mas o quê ela me deu foi uma "nuvem de pontos" (usei a função nnstart no matlab para realizar o treinamento)

como segue na imagem abaixo, a primeira figura é a regressão linear e a segunda é o que achei na rede  neural

A única maneira de se achar o coeficiente que a rede neural tentou prever é pelo que eu fiz ou existe algum outro método mais eficiente?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Veja se sua rede neural está usando função de ativação, se sim, precisa remover. Para usar uma perceptron para regressão precisa de uma saída linear.